# Saving an Image using entity framework CodeFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am new to entity framework and I am trying to go the Code First approach.  When defining one of my model classes I want one of the objects in the class to map to a Image column in my Sql Server Database.  What object type would I use here so that when the table is created it would make that column an Image column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use byte[] datatype on your objects, for Sql you can use varbinary(max) (as image data type will be removed from future sql version. [MSDN - Image datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

```
public byte[] yourFiles{get;set;}
```

you can configure like this using fluent api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomePOCOClass>().Property(p => p.yourFiles).HasColumnName("yourColumnName").HasMaxLength(SomeLength).HasColumnType("varbinary");
```

Comment: Will that create an Image column?

Comment: @esastincy check uodated ans.